# start nginx when upstream server cannot be resolved and still have proxy_pass URI/URI rewriting rules?

Tags: nginx

This nginx configuration works for me:

```
location /foo/ {
  proxy_pass http://a.bar.mesos/;
}
```

Note that both the `location` selector and the `proxy_pass` value are URIs. So you know, this affects how the URL is rewritten for the upstream server. As an example, `http://.../foo/bar` gets rewritten to `http://a.bar.mesos/bar`. If the `proxy_pass` value were `http://a.bar.mesos` without the trailing slash then the URL would be rewritten as `http://a.bar.mesos/foo/bar` which is incorrect for me.

As you may also know, if `a.bar.mesos` is not resolvable at nginx start time then nginx will not start. A way around this is mentioned in other questions on this site and it is to use a `resolver` directive and a variable like so:

```
location /foo/ {
  resolver 127.0.0.1;
  set $a_bar_mesos a.bar.mesos;
  proxy_pass http://$a_bar_mesos/;
}
```

Indeed this solves the problem of nginx not starting with an unresolvable host name but it also makes nginx no longer recognize that the `proxy_pass` value has a URI and so URL rewriting becomes incorrect for me. That is, it use the rewriting rules associated with a `proxy_pass` value of `http://a.bar.mesos` instead of `http://a.bar.mesos/`.

My question is, does anyone know how to start nginx with unresolvable host names and get the URI/URI URL rewriting rules?

So you know my use case, I use Mesos to launch programs onto a cluster of machines. The programs have well known names like `a.bar`. I use `mesos-dns` then to associate the program name `a.bar` with the hostname `a.bar.mesos` and the IP address of the machine that Mesos assigned to it. When the program is not running, `mesos-dns` removes the name `a.bar.mesos` from its registry. I use nginx to forward HTTP requests to the program via the above configuration. When I am restarting the server hosting nginx there is no guarantee that all of the programs being proxied to will be up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the URI/URI rewrite rule by using a `rewrite ... break` inside the same location, rather than using the `proxy_pass` to do it for you:

```
location /foo/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    set $a_bar_mesos a.bar.mesos;

    rewrite ^/foo(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://$a_bar_mesos;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.